# How get the image in the pdf forrmat in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to show the download the user profile in pdf format. That's working fine but the only thing is his image is not showing. I don't know how to handle the images in the pdf but I used the normal way to display image but indeed that's not working. Anyone know about how to display the image ?

```
<td width="400px;" style="text-align:left; padding:10px;">
 <img alt="Img" src="{{$student->photo->file}}" width="50px" height="50px">
</td>

//Controller

 public function downloadPDF($id) {
        $students = [Student::findOrFail($id)];
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.students.pdf', compact( 'students'));
        return $pdf->download('Student_Profile.pdf');
    }
```

Comment: If you post what you have tried thus far maybe we can help you unless of course your code is a state secret! 

Comment: So what part you wanna see ? I will show you

Comment: Well, how about the section where you are retrieving the image and inserting it into your document?

Comment: See the updated question pls

Comment: Could the issue involve the path to the image?

Comment: I did not see anything because of the path. But I showed how I try to put the image in my documents. Now I have no idea how to display image in pdf

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you

Comment: You should use the full filesystem path to your image, not the URL, in your view to let the pdf library you use find the image file.

Comment: Is the image shown when you view the `admin.students.pdf` view directly (without converting it to PDF)?